# What are "-dev" suffix in packages found in APT repositories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, lib

I've been trying to install the newest version of Emacs(25.3), and after running the configure.sh script found in the downloaded directory, it returned warnings that i didn't have some libraries installed, for instance libpng, libxpm and others which i actually had installed.

After installing the same packages with the "-dev" suffix it seemed to have fixed the issue and now the script could detect those libraries.

TL;DR My question is what does the "-dev" suffix denote in apt repositories, and in general all suffixes like "-dbg" etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on askubuntu.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Packages with the `-dev` suffix (debian/ubuntu) or `-devel` suffix (red hat/centos/fedora) typically contain the files necessary if you are going to be compiling software from source that uses the associated library.  They will typically contain C header files (`foo.h`) and the unversioned shared libraries (`libfoo.so`).  The non-dev package has only the versioned shared libraries (`libfoo.so.1.1`) that are required by compiled binaries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So they're basically the interface that you need to use them in your own software?

Comment: Sure, that's a reasonable way of stating it.